# Alpha Blending With Two Rendering Targets (DirectX or OpenGL)

Tags: opengl, colors, directx

I am trying to do the following:

- Create a transparent texture called T
- Render a textured quad called Q to T
- Render T to the screen

Note that the alpha component of T will be zero and the alpha component of Q could be less than one.

I need two alpha blending equations so that if I render multiple instances of Q to T (1st  blending equations used) and then render T (2nd blending euqations used), it would be the same as rendering multiple instances of Q directly to the screen.

I use this blending equation

```
color = src * srcAlpha + dst * (1 - srcAlpha)
alpha = 1 * srcAlpha + 0 * destAlpha
```

for the case when I render Qs directly to the screen, but cannot define two blending equations that achieve the same thing when I render to T first.

Note that T's pixels are initially fully transparent (alpha = 0) as I don't want it to overwrite the screen if it's not been draw to. Q may have any transparency level in each of its pixels.

Comment: Sorry, I've corrected my question zero should have been one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out, and given it's not something I've seen elsewhere on the internet, I hope this will help someone else...

For the first blend equation, for quads Q rendering to T:

Q -> T

```
color = src * srcAlpha + dst * (1 - srcAlpha)
alpha = 1 * srcAlpha + (1 - srcAlpha) * destAlpha
```

For the second blend equation, T going to the screen:

T -> S

```
color = src * 1 + dst * (1 - srcAlpha)
alpha = doesn't matter as screen alpha isn't used
```

**Explanation**

For Q -> T, the equation for the color components is as per the normal alpha blending equation:

```
color = src * srcAlpha + dst * (1 - srcAlpha)
```

however we need to make sure the alpha channel is set up for the second part. Because we are effectively pre-multiplying the alphas of Q when rendered to T using this blending equation, we only need the alpha in the second stage to determine how much to dim the color of the screen color by when rendering T, hence the alpha in the first equation is:

```
alpha = 1 * srcAlpha + (1 - srcAlpha) * destAlpha
```

but we only use it to fade the destination color behind the color of T in the second equation (we use 1 for src color as that was pre-multiplied by equation 1):

```
color = src * 1 + dst * (1 - srcAlpha)
```

In DirectX 11 this gives the same results whether equation 1 is used to render directly to the screen or both equations are used to render to T then the screen.

Code for DirectX 11 (for people who prefer real code):

1st equation:

```
D3D11_BLEND_DESC blend{};

blend.AlphaToCoverageEnable = FALSE;

auto& target = blend.RenderTarget[0];

target.BlendEnable = TRUE;
target.RenderTargetWriteMask = D3D11_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE_ALL;

target.SrcBlend = D3D11_BLEND_SRC_ALPHA;
target.DestBlend = D3D11_BLEND_INV_SRC_ALPHA;
target.BlendOp = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;

target.SrcBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_ONE;
target.DestBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_INV_SRC_ALPHA;
target.BlendOpAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
```

2nd equation:

```
D3D11_BLEND_DESC blend{};

blend.AlphaToCoverageEnable = FALSE;

auto& target = blend.RenderTarget[0];

target.BlendEnable = TRUE;
target.RenderTargetWriteMask = D3D11_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE_ALL;

target.SrcBlend = D3D11_BLEND_ONE;
target.DestBlend = D3D11_BLEND_INV_SRC_ALPHA;
target.BlendOp = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;

target.SrcBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_ZERO;
target.DestBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_ONE;
target.BlendOpAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
```

T is initially cleared to {0, 0, 0, 0}.

Comment: I don't think this is right. Looking at your Q->T alpha equation (alpha = 1 * srcAlpha + (1 - srcAlpha) * destAlpha). If you were to render two quads, both at 0.5 alpha, will make T's alpha 1.0, when it ought to be 0.75.

Comment: @Columbo, I think you're incorrect. If the quad is one pixel and has `color {c, c, c, 0.5}`, the alpha for the first quad rendered to T will be: `alpha = 1 * srcAlpha + (1 - srcAlpha) * destAlpha` where `srcAlpha = 0.5` and `destAlpha = 0` because `destAlpha` is the alpha for T which is initially zero. The second Q rendered over the top will be:  `srcAlpha = 0.5` and now in T `destAlpha = 0.5` (from previous rendered quad in T) which gives the correct alpha for T of `0.75` from `alpha = 1 * srcAlpha + (1 - srcAlpha) * destAlpha`. I have also tried it and seen it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is mathematically impossible using linear interpolation.

Let's say you have two transparent objects, `A` and `B`. You have your texture `T`, and the screen `S`. And `Blend` is the blend equation.

What you are doing with rendering to `T` is:

```
T = Blend(B, Blend(A, T))
S = Blend(T, S)

//Therefore
S = Blend(Blend(B, Blend(A, T)), S)
```

See how there are 3 separate blending operations here? You cannot do that with *two* blending operations. Which is all you would have if you render `A` and `B`.

Linear interpolation is neither [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) nor [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property). The order of blending operations *matters*. And the effect you achieve by writing to a temporary intermediate and blending that to the final buffer *cannot* be achieved without that intermediary.

There are blending operations that are associative and commutative. For example, additive. But that's almost certainly not going to achieve the visual effect you want, since it adds colors together. That may be something you could use, if you're doing HDR lighting. But there are many cases where it would be inappropriate.

Additive blending would involve a blend equation of the form:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE);
```

With the source alpha determining what percentage of the incoming color to add.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to reply. I have managed to figure this out. Maybe I asked the question badly, but I think the assumption that blend equations only do linear interpolation is incorrect. In the solution, my second equation is of the form `color = src * 1 + dst * (1 - srcAlpha)` which is not linear interpolation. It's only analogous to lerping if blending function `f(x)` is of the form `a * (x) + b * (1 - x)`, not say `a + b * (1 - x)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works when rendering Q into T:

```
color = src * srcAlpha + dst * (1 - srcAlpha)
alpha = (1 - destAlpha) * srcAlpha + 1 * destAlpha
```

Edit: Thinking about it, my answer won't result in the screen's alpha channel matching the alpha channel you describe when you're rendering direct into the screen. Your alpha blend mode when rendering direct to screen is very unusual. I'm not sure whether you really want the screen's alpha to represent the alpha of the last texture you rendered, or whether you don't actually care what the screen's alpha channel looks like. In most rendering situations people don't care about the state of the back buffer's alpha channel, hopefully that's the case here and my answer works for you.